# Set text in anchor tag(data-role="button") the text is collapsed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my JQuery Mobile(1.3.2) application used `<a data-role="button" >` and set the button text **dynamically using jquery**. The problem is when start scrolling the page the button text is collapsed like the below image. I didn't use any extra styles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar in browser it is working fine but in my device shows above prob..here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5yoy1m8a/

Comment: are you giving any style to the button text? please try to add same css class as using for other buttons, it looks like text font is bigger.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i didnt any styles...

Comment: it should be `$("#abtn .ui-btn-text").text("Dynamic Text");`

Comment: @Omar when the anchor(<a>) tag is dynamically added that time also the above problem persist..

Comment: how do you add it dynamically?

Comment: @Omar `var add = '<a data-role="button" >Dynamic text</a>';$("#table").after(add).parent().trigger('create');'

Comment: @Omar when adding like this also `$("#abtn .ui-btn-text").text("Dynamic Text");` collapse the text format

Comment: You need to _enhance_ dynamically injected button http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5yoy1m8a/2/

Comment: @Omar i need to insert dynamic values in my table after certain rows..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62099/discussion-between-omar-and-anu).

Comment: Please look at my answer..i saw your fiddle..do like the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar issue before like your's. I did like the following. After adding dynamic rows  you need set like

```
$(".yourinsertedbutton").trigger("pagecreate");
```

it resolves my issue.

Try this one

```
 $(".yourbtn").button('refresh');
```

OR try like this:

```
$('#yourbtn').parent().find('span').html("your text here");
```

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by0nsp0p/9/) line number 10 in script.

Comment: it resolves the issue but the cloning,is not possible..check http://jsfiddle.net/by0nsp0p/3/

Comment: yes this resolves the issue `$('#yourbtn').parent().find('span').html("your text here");`