# Jquery mobile dynamically inserted select option style issue collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my cordova app using Jquery mobile(v 1.3.2)  dynamically inserted select option style issue collapsed when scrolling in device.

**Note*** Initially loads fine, when scrolling the problem occur.

[image]

For dynamically add select option in table:

```
var options = '<option>8101</option>';
var orderLingerClone = '<tr><td><select id=productktnum'+orderLingerId+'>';
if(somval){
    orderLingerClone += options;
}
orderLingerClone += '</select><td><input type=text id=mBeskrevide'+orderLingerId+' /></td></tr>';

$("#orderlingerHeader").after(orderLingerClone).parent().trigger('create');
$("select#productktnum"+orderLingerId).selectmenu();
$("select#productktnum"+orderLingerId).selectmenu("refresh");
```

`orderlingerHeader` is nothing but table row(insert after that row).

and one more thing is after update the select option text from DB and display like:

```
$("#productktnum"+k).html("<option>"+results.rows.item(j).ProductNo+"</option>"); 
//$('#productktnum'+k).selectmenu();
$("select#productktnum"+k).selectmenu("refresh");
```

Update: Canvas sign field..[Sign plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn) when remove this working fine...

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="signaturePart">
        <div class="sigPad">
            <b><label data-i18n="kundens"></label></b>
            <ul type="none">
                <!-- <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" class="current"></a></li> -->
                <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear" data-i18n="clear"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="sig">
                <div class="typed"></div>
                <canvas width="550" height="200" id="mKundusskirt" class="pad"></canvas>
                <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried lot but nothing resloves my issue.

Please guide me to get away from this issue.

Comment: Maybe its the (<tr><td>) table tags that's causing that. Have you tried without?

Comment: can you maybe update this fiddle to reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cnrzcves/

Comment: @ezanker in browser it is working fine..in device only having the issue..

Comment: @Tasos i have other table like this working fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094484/set-text-in-anchor-tagdata-role-button-the-text-is-collapsed

Comment: @ezanker i have a canvas (sign field in my app) when remove this the problem not occur...

Comment: which device are you refering to, android, iphone?

Comment: @Tasos android nexus 7..